# Exceeded the maximum instruction count while exporting 600 contacts + groups

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I want to export my google contacts with their groups into a Google spreadsheet since the standard export file sucks.  My dataset is not excessive (32 groups and 600 contacts). What am I doing wrong? How can I limit the number of instructions so I don't hit this error anymore?

---

```
function GetGroups() {

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var blad6=ss.getSheets()[6];
  var vId;
  var vGroep;
  var lijn5=2;

  var contact = ContactsApp.getContacts();

  blad6.clearContents();
  blad6.getRange("A1").setValue("Naam");
  blad6.getRange("B1").setValue("Groep");
  blad6.getRange("C1").setValue("ID");

for (var i=0;i<contact.length;i++) {
    sleep(500);
    vId=contact[i].getId();
    vGroep=contact[i].getContactGroups();

    for (var j=0;j<vGroep.length;j++) {
      blad6.getRange("A" + (lijn5)).setValue(contact[i].getFullName());
      blad6.getRange("B" + (lijn5)).setValue(vGroep[j].getName());
      blad6.getRange("C" + (lijn5)).setValue(vId);
      lijn5++;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Thanks, that has resolved most of the problems. However, I'm still getting an Over Quota error on this section. How come? I'm constructing an array, just as you advized

```
function HaalGroepenOp() {

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var blad6=ss.getSheets()[6];
  var resultaat=new Array();

  var vId;
  var vGroep;
  var lijn=1;

  var contact = ContactsApp.getContacts();

  blad6.clearContents();
  resultaat[0]=[["Naam"],["Groep"],["ID"]];

for (var i=0;i<contact.length;i++) {
    vId=contact[i].getId();
    vGroep=contact[i].getContactGroups();

    for (var j=0;j<vGroep.length;j++) {
      resultaat[lijn]=[[contact[i].getFullName()],[vGroep[j].getName()],[vId]];
      lijn++;
    }
  }
  blad6.getRange(1,1,lijn,3).setValues(resultaat);
}
```

Comment: Check out the [Quota Limits](https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are making too many calls to the spreadsheet with setValue for each individual item.

You should be building arrays and then assigning the array to the spreadsheet using setValues().

```
  blad6.getRange("A1").setValue("Naam");
  blad6.getRange("B1").setValue("Groep");
  blad6.getRange("C1").setValue("ID");
```

should be:

```
blad6.getRange("A1:C1").setValues([["Naam","Groep","ID"]]);
```

Likewise, you should build an array with your loop and then assign the array to the spreadsheet in one batch using setValues()

See [Optimizing Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_common_tasks#OptimizeScripts)